# npm run production has suddenly stopped working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a server on which a Laravel-VueJs application is deployed. I used to push code there and run "npm run prod" to generate build. Today when I pushed it and ran the command the server started giving me errors.

deleted node_modules, cleared npm caches.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'production' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'preproduction', 'production', 'postproduction' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preproduction: @
6 info lifecycle @~production: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~production: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~production: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/CRA/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_$
9 verbose lifecycle @~production: CWD: /var/www/CRA
10 silly lifecycle @~production: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~production: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~production: Failed to exec production script
13 verbose stack Error: @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.c$
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /var/www/CRA
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-150-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "production"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ production script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Expected results : perfect build
Actual result: Build failed.

Comment: As of now we can't reproduce the issue because you didn't included a [mcve].

Comment: @NinoFiliu I can't even reproduce the error. It was working in my desktop, and I have the same environment on my server and it has suddenly halted.

Comment: Listen, as of now, you're just posting an error log - no code, no word about your local and server environment, etc. There is no way people can help you. Please visit SO's help page on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)